# Blazor (.NET 7) - Validating Complex Model (ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator is still on pre-release)

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

Good day everyone

I have created a Complex model (2 models on it), but the required fields do not validate upon submitting it, I search on the internet and stand upon Kudvenkat's video about complex model, but when I'm trying to put the "**ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator**" on my EditForm, it does not show. and then I tried to look for **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.DataAnnotations.Validation** but it does not show, then I check the pre-release and it shows, but the last update is last 2020, why does Microsoft do not include this on the latest updates (for the past 2 years), or did they add other features that as similar to this? I tried to search on it, but I failed, do you have any alternates for this?

I tried to use the code use by Kudvenkat

```
public class Employee
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [ValidateComplexType]
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    [Required]
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}
```

Here's on the razor page

```
<EditForm Model="@Employee">
    <ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator />
    <InputText id="firstName" @bind-Value="EditEmployeeModel.FirstName" />
    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => EditEmployeeModel.FirstName)" />
</EditForm>
```

I hope you can help me on this.

Thanks

Comment: I have the exact same question.  The latest is back from 2020.  Why is this not out of prerelease at this point?  It works, however,. I hate using pre-release package although this one does seem to work as expected